# Adding to one array is resulting in addition to another array in javascript and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html, set

I have a set of arrays created from different function constructors in this code:

```js
// The general purpose of a set is to make sure that it's elements are unique
function SetJs() {

  collection = [];
  this.has = (value) => {
    return collection.indexOf(value) !== -1;
  }

  this.add = (value) => {
    if (!this.has(value)) {
      collection.push(value);
      return `${value} added to set`;
    } else {
      return `${value} already part of set`;
    }
  }

  this.delete = (value) => {
    if (this.has(value)) {
      collection.splice(collection.indexOf(value), 1)
      return `${value} removed from set`;
    } else {
      return `${value} not found in set`;
    }
  }

  this.set = () => {
    return collection;
  }

  this.length = () => {
    return collection.length;
  }

}

var set1 = new SetJs();
var set2 = new SetJs();
let result;

const getSetByNumber = (setNumber) => {
  if (setNumber === 1) {
    return set1;
  } else {
    return set2;
  }
}

const addToSet = (setNumber) => {
  let set = getSetByNumber(setNumber);
  result = set.add(document.getElementById('input').value);
  printSet();
}


const deleteFromSet = (setNumber) => {
  let set = getSetByNumber(setNumber);
  result = set.delete(document.getElementById('input').value);
  printSet();
}

const printSet = () => {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
  document.getElementById('set1').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(set1.set());

  document.getElementById('set2').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(set2.set());
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Set implementation in javascript
</h1>
<label id="result"></label>


<br/>
<input id="input" placeholder="Enter a value" />
<button onClick="addToSet(1)">Add to set 1</button>
<button onClick="deleteFromSet(1)">Delete from set 1</button>

<button onClick="addToSet(2)">Add to set 2</button>
<button onClick="deleteFromSet(2)">Delete from set 2</button>

<br/> Set 1:
<div id="set1"></div>
Set 2:
<div id="set2"></div>
```

`set1` & `set2` are different set objects. However when I add to one the other also gets updated.

Why are Set 1 & 2 are getting updated at the same time?

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do not define the scope, it is treated as a global scoped variable. You need to define your `collection` as a scope in that function.

```js
// The general purpose of a set is to make sure that it's elements are unique
function SetJs() {

  let collection = [];
  this.has = (value) => {
    return collection.indexOf(value) !== -1;
  }

  this.add = (value) => {
    if (!this.has(value)) {
      collection.push(value);
      return `${value} added to set`;
    } else {
      return `${value} already part of set`;
    }
  }

  this.delete = (value) =>
    collection = collection.filter(item => item !== value);


  this.set = () => collection;

  this.length = () => collection.length;


}

var set1 = new SetJs();
var set2 = new SetJs();
let result;

const getSetByNumber = (setNumber) => {
  if (setNumber === 1) {
    return set1;
  } else {
    return set2;
  }
}

const addToSet = (setNumber) => {
  let set = getSetByNumber(setNumber);
  result = set.add(document.getElementById('input').value);
  printSet();
}


const deleteFromSet = (setNumber) => {
  let set = getSetByNumber(setNumber);
  result = set.delete(document.getElementById('input').value);
  printSet();
}

const printSet = () => {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
  document.getElementById('set1').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(set1.set());

  document.getElementById('set2').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(set2.set());
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Set implementation in javascript
</h1>
<label id="result"></label>


<br/>
<input id="input" placeholder="Enter a value" />
<button onClick="addToSet(1)">Add to set 1</button>
<button onClick="deleteFromSet(1)">Delete from set 1</button>

<button onClick="addToSet(2)">Add to set 2</button>
<button onClick="deleteFromSet(2)">Delete from set 2</button>

<br/> Set 1:
<div id="set1"></div>
Set 2:
<div id="set2"></div>
```

Comment: Your remove function is also not correct, I fixed it in my edit.